# Mapreduce with Riak

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, riak

Does anyone have example code for mapreduce for Riak that can be run on a single Riak node.

Comment: Dobre den . Jak se mas? (the only czech i remember from when I lived near Olomouc). I did research this, but there are no working examples on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd ~/riak
erl -name zed@127.0.0.1 -setcookie riak -pa apps/riak/ebin
```

In the shell:

```
# connect to the server
> {ok, Client} = riak:client_connect('riak@127.0.0.1').
{ok,{riak_client,'riak@127.0.0.1',<<6,201,208,64>>}}

# create and insert objects
> Client:put(riak_object:new(<<"groceries">>, <<"mine">>, ["eggs", "bacons"]), 1).
ok
> Client:put(riak_object:new(<<"groceries">>, <<"yours">>, ["eggs", "sausages"]), 1).
ok

# create Map and Reduce functions
> Count = fun(G, 'undefined', 'none') ->
            [dict:from_list([{I, 1} || I <- riak_object:get_value(G)])]
          end.
#Fun<erl_eval.18.105910772>
> Merge = fun(Gcounts, 'none') ->
            [lists:foldl(fun(G, Acc) ->
                           dict:merge(fun(_, X, Y) -> X+Y end, G, Acc)
                         end, dict:new(), Gcounts)] 
          end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>

# do the map-reduce
> {ok, [R]} = Client:mapred([{<<"groceries">>, <<"mine">>},
                             {<<"groceries">>, <<"yours">>}],
                            [{'map', {'qfun', Count}, 'none', false},
                             {'reduce', {'qfun', Merge}, 'none', true}]).           
{ok,[{dict,...

> dict:to_list(R).
[{"eggs",2},{"susages",1},{"bacons",1}]
```

For the server I used absolutely default config:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.basho.com/riak/
$ cd riak
$ ./rebar compile generate
$ cd rel
$ ./riak/bin/riak start
```

Comment: Yes and I get several different errors depending on the configuration I use. eg:

exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{badarg,[{ets,match,[nodelocal_ring,{ring,'$1'}]},
                                                                      {riak_ring_manager,get_my_ring,0},
                                                                      {riak_mapreduce_fsm,init,1},
                                                                      {gen_fsm,init_it,6},
                                         {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}
: is not very helpful

Comment: Does the Map Reduce example from the manual work for you? If so maybe you could help me and talk me through getting it working?

Comment: The documentation is a bit inconsistent, as in the client examples, bucket and object names are binaries, but in the map-reduce example they use atoms and strings.

Comment: Zed, you are a star! It works!!! Now, I'll try to get it working from modules, but that was a great help. :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I replaced the atoms for Strings and my previous code works now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [example](http://seancribbs.com/tech/2010/02/07/wrap-your-sql-head-around-riaks-map-reduce/) of how to do a MapReduce using JavaScript functions.